# I want to use imshow() in colab, but it doesn't work

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, opencv, imshow

Based on a previous thread I tried

```
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow()
```

But when I run it the following error came up:

```
File "<ipython-input-10-7cdf619df240>", line 1
    from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow()
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 3):

Dont use `()` while importing

Use

```
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `imshow()` in colab also. For that reason follow my steps...

1. Click on files from left side. Then simply click on 'Mount Drive' option. It will take some time.
2. Then you can easily use your `imshow` function normally.

N.B. you have use your file location in this format =>>>

```
!ls "/content/drive/My Drive/....."  # To go to the file location
!cp -r "/content/drive/My Drive/....."  # to copy a file to Colab
```

Then use the following codes =>>

```
image = cv2.imread("/content/drive/My Drive/......../image.bmp", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
plt.imshow(image, cmap = "gray"), plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```